# Position of the adjective of a genitive

Tags: translation-check, translation-explanation

Given the following sentence:

> The ways of the high mountains are rough.

Is there any reason to prefer "Altorum montium itinera confragosa sunt" over "Montium altorum itinera cofragosa sunt"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference isn't one of meaning, but emphasis. As a rule of thumb, whichever word you put first is getting the most emphasis in the sentence. But Latin word order is extremely free, and *altōrum montium itinera*, *montium altōrum itinera*, *itinera montium altōrum*, *altōrum itinera montium*, and so on are all perfectly valid ways to phrase it.

Out of those options, *itinera montium altōrum* reads the most neutrally to me: no specific emphasis, a default and unmarked way to phrase it. *Altōrum itinera montium*, on the other hand, puts a *lot* of emphasis on the height; breaking up a phrase like this tends to be a poetic thing.

Comment: Indeed, I always forget about the emphasis.